Google Chrome Back/Forward Cached page removal
Any idea how to remove a Back/Forward Cached page process on latest Google Chrome (131) on Windows 10?
Background is that something had set a custom default search engine/homepage which I've cleaned up but I can't seem to find/remove the attached process which even if I end the process it seems to recreate on next Chrome restart.
I've reset all the chrome://flags to default and reset the settings to no avail.
I've no idea who search-sprint[dot]com are and they don't seem to have any presence online.
Any idea how to remove this process and prevent it returning on next restart?

After much hunting the solution for anyone else finding this is that the back/forward cache is a symptom and the issue was that the start page had been changed to load from search-sprint[dot]com but looked a lot like a normal Google start page until I spotted it was using affiliate links, upon resetting that the issue has cleared.
